# checking checkbox values onclick (my code not working!)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

hello I have problem in reading and sending checkbox value I tried using **ajax** but it didn't work
what the wrong with my ajax????!!!
" what I really need is to retrieve the value " . $row['ID'] . " and write statement to insert value to the db in case it was checked ?!"

```
function defaultt(id) {
        $.ajax({

            type : "POST",
            data : "id=" + id,
            url : "defaultt.php",
            success : function(msg) {
                $('#' + id).fadeOut(300);
            }
        });
```

code:

```
<td><form><input type="checkbox" name="state" id="state"class="check"  checked onClick='javascript:defaultt(" . $row['ID'] . ");' >
```

retrieve code in other page.php:

```
<?php $id1 = intval($_POST['id']);
```

if (isset($id1)) {} ?>

I also used this code but didn't work :(

```
    <?php if ($_POST['state']){?>
 <script type=text/javascript>
function validate(){
if(state.checked == 1){
      alert("checked") ;}else{
 alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.")
 }
 }
 </script>
  <?php}?>
```

Comment: What does 'it didn't work' mean? An error? The wrong data? Some of the right data? Too much data?

Comment: you sent id `"id="` not state `$_POST['state']`

Comment: In the first version of your function you pass in an id but don't ever check the current `checked` state of the checkbox. Note also that you don't need the `javascript:` label in an inline event attribute.

Comment: yah sorry I should write: $id1 = intval($_POST['id']);
if (isset($id1)) but still not work :(

Comment: mr.nnnnn how can I check if it checked or not?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    function validate(){
    if($("#state").is(":checked")){
        alert("checked") ;
      }
      else{
        alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.")
    }
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mN5Te/)

Comment: `$("#state").prop('checked')` is an alternative

Comment: thanks for your time but I put this function in the header section but didn't work and what I really need is to retrieve the value " . $row['ID'] . " :( any idea?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check"/>
```

**JS**

```
$('#check').change(function() {

    var $check = $(this),
        $div = $check.parent();

    if ($check.prop('checked')) {
        alert("Check");
        $div.addClass('test');

    } else {
        alert("Uncheck");
        $div.removeClass('test');

    }

});
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/jfzAu/)**

Comment: Why use `$check.prop('checked')` when you can just say `this.checked`?

Answer (score 0):

```
To check Checkbox true: ($('#id').prop('checked') == true)
$('#state').on('click',function(){

if ($('#state').prop('checked') == true)
  {
 alert('checked');
  }
    else
      { alert('Not checked'); }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uEHdU/1/)